# Having trouble with IfStrEq from xstring

Tags: xstring

precondition: The filename is `lab00.tex`

```
\def\fn{\jobname}

\StrLeft{\fn}{1}[\firstChar]

\IfStrEq{\firstChar}{l}{true}{false}
```

Answer (score 3):

The result is “false”, because although the package claims to compare “strings”, it actually takes into consideration category codes.

The first character in your `\jobname` is an `l` of category code 12, by general rule of TeX about generated strings of characters. However, you're comparing it with a standard category code 11 `l`.

You could do

```latex
\def\fn{\jobname}
\StrLeft{\fn}{1}[\firstChar]
\IfStrEq{\firstChar}{\detokenize{l}}{true}{false}
```

because `\detokenize` uses the same internal machinery that outputs characters with category code 12.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!